# Finding all nodes on a graph that are N nodes away

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

> You and a few friends are playing a board game. The board of the game is laid out in a large interconnected graph that has many loops. Each player starts at a different location on the board. When it is your turn, you get to roll anything between one to six 6-sided dice (in other words, anything from a 1-36). How do you determine every space that you can possibly go to in a single turn from your current location? *(Example: I roll a 13. Find all spots on the board that are 13 spaces away from me.)* You can only move forwards but you can loop around to traverse a net total of less than your roll.
>
> Example: If this is your graph and you start at the top-left corner and you rolled a 6, then one place you can move is *down, right, right, up, left, left.* However you cannot move *right, left, right, left, right, left*.

```
  o---o---o---o---o
  |       |   |
  o---o---o---o
```

Are there any algorithms available that do better than depth-first search?

Comment: Is the "Are the any algorithms..." part of the assignment or _your_ question? Also, can there be loops in the path, e.g. could you go back and forth between two nodes 6 times, then go one further?

Comment: @tobias_k It's my question.

Comment: You should use breadth-first search. It's optimal.

Comment: @ciamej Why breadth-first?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes there are loops in the graph. You cannot go backwards but you can always loop around. (Actually, let me edit the question to specify that.)

Comment: @tobias_k You can essentially move around the loops and can visit the same edge more than once. However you cannot revisit the same edge in succession. i.e. If I visit an adjacent node using an edge, I cannot backtrack on that edge and let that count towards my total.

Comment: Depth-first search (with recursion depth limited by an additional parameter) can be used to solve the problem described (of which you apparently are well aware). Every edge within the area of reachable successors will be traversed at most once. If the input graph is a tree, it will be traversed _exactly_ once. I don't see a possibility better than that; otherwise, the result of the algorithm is impossible to depend on the entire input. A sub-linear running time is a rare phenomenon.

Comment: Actually, you don't need any kind of graph traversal for this problem. If `M` is the adjacency matrix of the graph, such that `M(i,j) = 1` if there is an edge from node `i` to node `j` and `M(i,j) = 0` if there isn't an edge, then `M**k` (the `k`-th power of `M`, *i.e.*, `M` multiplied by itself `k` times) is such that `(M**k)(i,j)` = number of different paths from `i` to `j`.

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by 'better'. Visiting less nodes? Then the answer is **No** if the graph has no circles because you only visit all notes required once.

Comment: Final question about the revisiting-nodes-and-edges thing. Assume you have a cyclic graph `A-B-C-D-A` (i.e. D loops back to A) and have to go 13 steps starting from A. Without going back the same edge, you could only do three full circles left or right and then one more step, i.e. `B` and `D` would be reachable in 13 steps, but not A and C, is this correct?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, this should be correct.

Comment: It looks like a naive depth-first-search wouldn't be enough; but Dijkstra's algorithm (which is basically breadth-first-search) would work well, and can be capped not to go over 13 steps.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to actually traverse the graph at all to solve this problem.

The graph can be encoded by its **adjacency matrix**: a matrix `M` such that `M(i,j) = 1` if there is an edge from node `i` to node `j` and `M(i,j) = 0` if there isn't an edge.

This matrix has a super cool property: for any nonnegative integer `k`, `M**k` (the `k`-th power of `M`, *i.e.*, `M` multiplied by itself `k` times) is such that `(M**k)(i,j)` = number of different walks from `i` to `j`.

If `(M**k)(i,j) > 0`, then node `i` can be reached from node `j` in exactly `k` moves. Note that, if you make sure that every node had an edge to itself, *i.e.*, if the diagonal of `M` is full of `1`s, then the nodes that can be reached in exactly `k` moves are the same as the nodes that can be reached in at most `k` moves.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Matrix_powers

In most programming languages, there are libraries that handle matrices and matrix operations quite efficiently, so that taking a matrix to a power can be much faster than actually visiting the nodes of a graph one after the other.

On the other hand, if the graph is huge and `k` is small, and you are only interested in one starting node, then calculating `M**k` might be less efficient than graph traversal, since `M**k` answers the question for every node of the graph, rather than just for the starting node you are interested in.

But if you are interested in all possible starting nodes or if `k` is close to the diameter of the graph, then computing `M**k` is most likely the best option.

Comment: While correct, I'm not sure whether this can be called _better_ than depth-first search. The running time of depth-first search would be `O(|E|)` regardless of the desired distance `k` while the running time of matrix exponentiation would be `O(|E|^{2k})` where `|E| is the number of edges`. Furthermore, the matrix exponentiation would not benefit from the sparsity of the graph.

Comment: This is interesting, but (a) is this actually faster than actually doing a DFS or BFS, and (b) would this work to find al the nodes that are _exactly_ 13 turns away considering loops?

Comment: Yes, it specifically gives you the number of walks of length exactly 13. If you want to know which nodes can be reached in exactly 13 moves, **and** cannot be reached in 12 moves or less, then you should compute both `M**12` and `M**13` (note that computing `M**13` from `M**12` is fast, since `M**13 = M * M**12`).

Comment: Does it take into account the restriction that you cannot walk back using the same edge as in the previous step?

Comment: The distinction between "exactly 13" and "at most 13" is done by deciding whether there is an edge from a node to itself; if there is, then you can "pass" one of your 13 moves; if there isn't, then you must move exactly 13 steps.

Comment: @Codor: I recommend you change your matrix exponentiation algorithms; the ones you are using right now appear to be particularly inefficient ;)

Comment: @ciamej: Oops, no, I did not notice that restriction

Answer (score 2):

With the restriction that you can go in circles, but not directly back to the node you came from, this is in fact quite an interesting problem. In particular, you can neither just do a BFS or DFS and prune all nodes you've already visited in fewer moves, nor would the clever matrix multiplication work.

Instead, you could use a variant of DFS, but you will have to keep track of both the number of moves you can reach a node in, and the node you came from when visiting that node, and only prune branches if you have seen that *exact* combination before -- not if you were reaching the node in *fewer* moves, or coming from another node.

Basic implementation in Python and example:

```py
def search(graph, start, moves):
    stack = [(start, 0, -1)]
    distance = {i: set() for i in range(moves+1)}
    while stack:
        node, dist, prev = stack.pop()
        if (node, prev) in distance[dist]: continue
        distance[dist].add((node, prev))
        if dist < moves:
            stack.extend((x, dist+1, node) for x in graph[node] if x != prev)
    return {node for (node, prev) in distance[moves]}

# 1---2---3---4---5
# |       |   |
# 6---7---8---9
g = {1: [2,6], 2: [1,3], 3: [2,4,8], 4: [3,5,9], 5: [4],
     6: [1,7], 7: [6,8], 8: [3,7,9], 9: [4,8]}
print(search(g, 1, 13))
# {8, 2, 4, 6}
```